# visually debug GTK3 applications (GtkInspector / gtkparasite)

Tags: linux, debugging, themes, gtk3

Trying to debug a GTK theme, I modified. Having corrected most of the issues with the theme, I Still cannot figure out, what color setting is responsible for background color in some input-fields or text-views.

#### SETUP

I can start [GtkInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) as well as [gtkparasite](http://chipx86.github.io/gtkparasite/) with Gtk3 applications (starting those debuggers as described on the given pages).

I'm sure, the debugger attached to the right application, because I can

- change the program's theme
- show graphic updates
- show pixel cache ...

#### PROBLEM

In the left selection pane (widget-treeview expected) is only one element: "GtkSettings"

Tried with:

- meld
- synaptic
- wireshark
- zenity --calendar

#### EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:

Be able to

- select widgets either from the **missing** widget-treeview, or when locating them with the 'target button'
- examine and change their parameters

#### SYSTEM INFORMATION

OS & all programs / packages: Debian 8 x86_64 (up-to-date: 09.01.2015)

### QUESTION

1. How can I debug my GTK-theme?
2. Does anyone else experience problems with the GtkInspector (is this a bug)?

Comment: Did you use the "inspect" button and click on a widget?

Comment: This [screenshot](https://hitzkopf.at/files/GTK-inspector.png) shows, how my Gtk Inspector looks like.  If you mean the "Select an Object" button on the left top - yes, I tried that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem with GtkInspector on Debian Jessie and I solved it by calling terminal and typing next :

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

this enables GtkInspector shorcut buttons just run your application and press

```
Control-Shift-I or Control-Shift-D
```

I hope it helps

Comment: That just works :') - Tnx! (Don't know why this is necessary, though)

Comment: I have the same problem as described in the question. When I try to run the suggested command under Debian Jessie I get `No such schema 'org.gtk.Settings.Debug'`.

Comment: @cgogolin you have to install `libgtk-3-dev` to get the debug schema.

Comment: @LéoLam - Nope, installing that made no difference.  It's already installed.  I also get No such schema.

Comment: But these shourtcuts are working as per the applications opened. For example if I want to inspect VS Code and I open it and press Ctrl+Shift+I then it formats the files and Ctrl+Shift+D opens the Debug menu. Same issue with the browsers. So how to open GTK inspector in these cases?

Answer (score 8):

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector misses to tell people to install "libgtk-3-dev"!!!

1. Install the package [https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=amd64&keywords=libgtk-3-dev libgtk-3-dev]
2. Start from terminal with:

   GTK_DEBUG=interactive gedit/gnome-terminal/nautilus/etc